# Helm using different values.yaml without CDing into deployment directory

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, helm3

I have my values.yaml in my_project_directory under deployment as below

```
C:\Users\Username\IdeaProjects\my-project\deployment\values.yaml
```

I need to use different values.yaml based on certain triggers in AzureDevops.

Current way I am running is (This runs fine and uses values.yaml)

```
helm install my-app-name ./deployment/ --namespace=my-namespace-name
```

I have two other values.yaml as below

```
C:\Users\Username\IdeaProjects\my-project\deployment\values_dev.yaml
C:\Users\Username\IdeaProjects\my-project\deployment\values_preprod.yaml
```

and can run using respective commands

```
helm install my-app-name . -f values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name
helm install my-app-name . -f values_preprod.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name
```

These work fine but I have to cd into deployment and run these. Anyway I can run it from project root directory?

Tried this

```
helm install my-app-name -f ./deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name
```

Got this error

```
Error: must either provide a name or specify --generate-name
```

Also tried this

```
 helm install my-app-name -f ./deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name --generate-name
```

Got this error

```
Error: failed to download "my-app-name" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Also tried this

```
helm install my-app-name ./deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name
```

Got this error

```
Error: file 'C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\my-project\deployment\values_dev.yaml' seems to be a YAML file, but expected a gzipped archive
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the arguments. The working command contains helm app name(my-app-name) and directory (.), but the failing command missing the directory name. Note: The assumption is that you are trying to install the chart from local path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands worked for me to use different values.yaml from the root folder (All these 3 values files are under deployment folder)

```
helm install my-app-name ./deployment/ --values ./deployment/values.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name

helm install my-app-name ./deployment/ --values ./deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name

helm install my-app-name ./deployment/ --values ./deployment/values_preprod.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name
```

Answer (score 1):

run from the project root directory =

`helm install my-app-name . -f deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name`

Comment: Thanks Philip Wesz for your response. But I got below error when I tried to run the command. "Error: create: failed to create: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728". I made some changes to your command and it worked, I will add it as my answer to this thread.

Comment: Your command down below is the same as mine : -f is the short version of --values and . should be the helm chart root as you can see here at the chart layout https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/

I would advise to use helm like thise:

Comment: DEV: `helm install my-app-name <CHART_ROOT> -f ./deployment/values.yaml -f ./deployment/values_dev.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name`


PREPROD: `helm install my-app-name <CHART_ROOT> -f ./deployment/values.yaml -f ./deployment/values_preprod.yaml --namespace=my-namespace-name`